# Using as with @forward in sass?

Tags: css, angular, sass

The angular material components has the following sass code in one of the modules [(_layout-common.import.scss)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/style/_layout-common.import.scss):

```
@forward 'layout-common' as mat-*;
```

Curious what the `as mat-*` part does?

The `layout-common` has the following code:

```
// This mixin ensures an element spans to fill the nearest ancestor with defined positioning.
@mixin fill {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Does the `mat-*` part affect the `fill` mixin name?

So if we `@use` the module that has the `@forward` rule in it as something like:

```
@use '../../somemodule' as test;
```

Would we call the `fill` mixin as:

```
@include test.mat-fill() ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can add a prefix to all the member names of the module getting imported using the `@forward` at-rule

```
@forward "<url>" as <prefix>-*
```

and later we can use with prefix

```
@use "layout"

div
  @include main.<prefix>-fill
```

You can check the docs for reference: [sass @forward docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward)